# Getting an array from a Mongo DB. UnhandledPromiseRejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mongodb-query

I am struggling with a function meant to extract an array from a Mongo database (in Node JS) and return it. Even though the idea is simple and I have written this kind of code a number of times; I am missing something.

Here is the code for the function:

```
function getDBArray(reqID) {
  MongoClient.connect(databaseUri, {useUnifiedTopology: true}, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('getDBArray: Error = ' + err)
      throw err
    }

    const db = client.db()
    let srchQuery = {}
    srchQuery['fieldID'] = reqID
    db.collection('theList', async function (err, collection) {
      try {
        await collection.find(srchQuery, {'target': true}).toArray(function (err, items) {
          if (err) throw err

          const resultArray = items;
          client.close();

          return resultArray;
        })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log('-catch (getDBArray)- ::>> ' + error)
      }
    })
  });
} /* End of getDBArray */
```

This is the calling code:

```
let myArray = getDBArray(dataID)
myArray.forEach(element => {
  console.log('myArray:'+element)
});
```

And this is what I keep getting in the logs:

```
...+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property   'forEach' of undefined
...+00:00 app[web.1]: at .... (/app/server.js:55:21)
...+00:00 app[web.1]: at ....
......
...+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag...
...+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can anyone see something I am not doing right in the function in order to hit this issue?

Comment: you have to wrap getDBArray content with new promise. then resolve, reject inside the promise

Comment: OK. How should I do that? I have already tried several variations of my code and it did not work. So I must be missing the proper way to do it.

Comment: Also, why not use Mongoose? Makes your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap function conmtent with promise :

```js
function getDBArray(reqID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(databaseUri, {
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }, function(err, client) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('getDBArray: Error = ' + err)
                reject(err)
            }

            const db = client.db()
            let srchQuery = {}
            srchQuery['fieldID'] = reqID
            db.collection('theList', async function(err, collection) {
                try {
                    await collection.find(srchQuery, {
                        'target': true
                    }).toArray(function(err, items) {
                        if (err) reject(err)

                        const resultArray = items;
                        client.close();

                        resolve(resultArray);
                    })
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(err)
                }
            })
        });
    })
}
```

Then call :

```js
getDBArray(dataID).then((myArray) => {
    myArray.forEach(element => {
        console.log('myArray:' + element)
    });
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: It worked. So you are obviously right. But I thought, since I was using async - await I would not have to use promises myself. I still need to improve my understanding of the subject. Thank you!